# How to solve the circled question?

Tags: logarithms

I always face problem in solving such questions. Can you please explain the approach to solve such questions.And please give full explanation for this question(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ1hY.jpg)

Comment: The first thing that stands out to me is that they never said anything about _finding_ the solution. Have you heard about the intermediate value theorem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the following identity:

> $$
> A^{\log_B C} = C^{\log_B A}
> $$

To see why this identity is true, take the $\log_B$ of both sides and apply power rule. Now apply the identity to your problem with $A = x$ and $C = 2$ so that you can collect like terms.